# Why does another user see no data in an SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report which always displays data when I run it. I have a user who frequently does not see data. I use the same parameters as him, etc. 
The data source for the report uses a service account so we're not using our own credentials to get the data. But I can't help but think it's got something to do with our logins.
I do make frequent changes to the report definition but I've set the processing options to "Do not cache".

Comment: He doesn't see ANY data, or different data?  Does he ever see any data?

Comment: He says he sees data sometimes but whenever I run it from his desk I get the same results as always: some parameter combinations (e.g. vendor#) will return the same data I get, others return nothing. We never get different data; either he gets what I get or he gets nothing at all.

Comment: Probably would need more information, i.e. it's randomly returning wrong data just from one PC, or his login on any PC?   Just this one query? What if you break the data down to a new report/simpler query.